# Estimate the angles of orientation (alpha,beta and gamma) by camera calibration

Tags: math, geometry, physics, matlab

I'm trying to estimate the three angles of orientation by camera calibration. I'm using matlab toolbox for calibration process.

Matlab camera calibration Toolbox process return the Rotation vector:

`omc_ext = [ 2.181316    2.182162    -0.076635 ]`

and Rotation matrix:

```
Rc_ext = [ 

-0.000242    0.999992    0.003935

0.997253     0.000533    -0.074075

-0.074076    0.003906    -0.997245 ]
```

How it possible to estimate the three angles of orientation from the above information ?

Comment: Did you tried the tsai-algorithm.

Comment: I'm using the general matlab camera calibration. check the link below: 
vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/htmls/example.html .

There are implementations for Zhengyou Zhang's and Heikkil's algorithms. I'm trying to figure-out the way to estimate the three angles.

Comment: Try http://www.flipcode.com/documents/matrfaq.html#Q37; also if your purpose is calibration, you should only need the inverse of the matrix, which btw is simply M(^T) [transpose] for rotation matrices.

Comment: The order of orientation gives different results for Euler angles. Do you have any idea about the order of orientation angles that matlab use in camera calib; for example (alpha,beta and gamma , beta,alpha gamma, gamma,beta and alpha ..etc) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three angles you are looking for are called Euler angles and they are not unique unless you have more information about the order in which the rotations are performed. Usually it's best to just work with the 3x3 rotation matrix unless you have some special need to know the angles.

Mathworld lists the trig equations necessary to calculate the Euler angles from the rotation matrix.

> http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerAngles.html

Comment: That's correct. There is no unique solution unless we have the order of orientation. Unfortunately, I did not find any clue in Matlab about the order of orientation till now!.